# Where can I find yoga vashishta in pdf format?

Tags: resource, yoga-vashishtha

I wanted to download Yoga Vashishta in PDF format with commentary in English by a reliable source. Where can I get it?

Comment: In which language are you looking for? Can you please add more clarity? Is any language fine?

Comment: https://archive.org/details/ShriYogavasishtha1 in Hindi & Marathi

Answer (score 3):

Yoga Vasistha (by Gita Press) in PDF format can be found on [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/YogaVasisthaByGitaPress)

Answer (score 2):

If the OP is interested in English version

1. He can read [here](https://selfdefinition.org/yoga/Yoga-Vasistha-125-pages.pdf)
2. [Yoga Vasishta Sara](http://sageramana.org/files/Yoga%20Vasishtha%20Sara.pdf) of Ramana Ashram can also be read.
3. The Yoga Vasishtha of The Divine Life Society can be read [here](http://www.dlshq.org/religions/yogavasishtha.htm).

Comment: You are ask and confirm in which language the OP is looking translation. It will be more accurate.

Comment: The other answer contains link to Hindi version.  Hence,  I gave links to English version. :-) @Sarvabhouma